# Vue & Typescript: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element | NodeListOf<Element>' Vetur(2339)

Tags: typescript

## Intro.

First time working on a Vue project with Typescript, so, would appreciate any help on this.

## Problem.

[image]

Specific error: `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element | NodeListOf<Element>'. Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.Vetur(2339)`.

## Commentary.

I've been looking around a bit, and I saw a couple of similar errors with people, but mostly, complains or issues, not exactly my case.

## Outro.

Any elaboration needed I am open to present, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `(selectQuery(selector) as HTMLElement).style.display`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to check it out and if it worked, I'll flag it, I've already thought of doing that... but, I just thought it would complain. @Phil